# how do you add a folder to git that contains submodules these being the base items that npx (create react app) does

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github

So I'm trying to add a folder for an amplify app which I started a react app inside. Doing `git add .` doesn't transfer the contents of the folder to Github just the folder with nothing inside. doing ```git add -f --all doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I figured out what was wrong in the tutorial for this aws amplify module i needed to make the git in the app folder not outside so using git add . worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
git add .*/*
```

Just be careful with other `.folders` that you have in your dir, you should create a `.gitignore` file to prevent uploading those folders.

Or in the worst-case scenario you can just run:

```
git add .<folder_name>/*
```

Comment: using .*/* yeilds error of did not match anyfiles

Comment: this amplifyapp folder has submodules because of react i just don't know how to make git add everything in the folder

Comment: really? because it worked in my local. could you post an example of a dir and file so I can try to reproduce it?

Comment: its ok i figured it out